# How to unset field from Document

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I have one document in which I want to remove one field. I got answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757959/how-to-unset-all-records-string-in-mongodb-using-php/11761315#11761315). But, It is for core PHP code and I want in CakePHP how to unset field from document.

I tried following code in CakePHP.

```
$this->MyModal->id = $id;
$this->MyModal->updateAll(
                        array('myField' => array('$exists' => true)),
                        array('unset' => array('myField' => true))
                );
```

**Edit**

I also tried

```
$this->MyModal->updateAll(
    array('$unset' => array('myField' => 1))
 );
```

But it does not work.How can unset field?

Comment: Operators are all prefixed with `$` so it should be `$unset`

Comment: @NeilLunn I also tried with `$unset` but it give Exception.

Comment: What exception? Also what does the data look like?

Comment: Which plugin are you using to connect mongodb to cakephp?

Comment: @NeilLunn I got this exception `localhost:27017: unknown top level operator: \$unset`

Comment: @PabloFlores I used `Mongodb` plugin

Comment: At a stab you seem to be trying to apply MongoDB `.update()` method logic to a method that does not strictly do that. You probably need to call something like [getMongoCollection()](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/Model/Datasource/MongodbSource.php#L359) in order to use the native driver object and features.

Comment: @PabloFlores your given link answer do not accepted and I also tried that answer but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using wrong the update all method. First you must provide an array with the new values you want for your fields and then you should pass an array with the search criteria. So in order for it to work you could write something like

```
 $conditions=array('myField'=>array('$exists'=>true));
 $this->MyModal->updateAll(
       array('$unset'=>array('myfield'=>1)),
       $conditions//array of search conditions
    )
```

Comment: Check the name of your collection, also you must pass an array of conditions or in case you want to alter all documents you must provide an empty array